# Laravel - "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm using host gator server, and I have this problem. I don't know do I need to restart the server, and I don't know how to do that. I already changed everything in the env file but I still have the same issue. Can someone fix this?

Comment: do you have a root user with no password on your server!

Comment: @Rabah No, we have a user with password

Comment: @Rabah Help if you can please, I need to deploy this website tonight...

Comment: is your problem solved @Vesko_dev

Comment: check my answer @EmtiazZahid

Answer (score 2):

I fixed. In bootstrap cache memory I had config file and the website using that data, not the new one. I just delete that file and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

check database.php in config folder and set true credential in connection => mysql section.
check mysql port in your server and set correct port .

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => '127.0.0.1'
        'port' => // your mysql server port often is 3306
        'database' => //yourdata base name 
        'username' => //correct user name
        'password' => //correct password
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```

Answer (score 0):

if in issue in live server

Please check .env

Some like issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94asu.png)

remove second parameter
after
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to config your .env file with correct credentials.